# Image only appear when clicking

Tags: beamer, graphics, overlays, slideshow

I'm new to latex. I'm building a presentation slides, and I need to show some images only when clicking (or pressing right arrow)

I've tried both of the following ways mentioned in other questions, but none worked for me:

***First:*** Inserting numbering in `includegraphices` inside of `<>`

```
\begin{frame}{SomeFrame}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics<0->[scale=.5]{SomeImage.png}
\end{center}
\caption{SomeCaption}
\label{fig:SomeImage}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

***Second:*** is using `\onslide<1->{}`

```
\begin{frame}{SomeFrame}
\onslide<1->{
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics<0->[scale=.5]{SomeImage.png}
\end{center}
\caption{SomeCaption}
\label{fig:SomeImage}
\end{figure}
}
\end{frame}
```

In both ways, I've tried once with `<0->` and `<1->`. However, pictures are there without me clicking. ***What should I do?***

Comment: Are you using Beamer to make your slides? (I edited the tags under the assumption that the answer is yes. Feel free to clarify/edit if it is not correct.)

Comment: Try `\includegraphics<2->[scale=.5]{SomeImage}`: first overlay without image and second overlay with your image.

Comment: Some offtopic comments: Don't use `begin{center}` inside a figure, use `\centering` instead. And since `beamer` does not use floats, you do not need floating specifier like `[h!]`.

Comment: @WillieWong, Yes I'm using beamer.

Comment: @AhmedWas And does Paul Gaborits suggestion solve your problem?

Comment: @PaulGaborit As your comments sounds like the answer to this question, would you like to write one?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the image to appear on the second slide of the frame, use

```
\includegraphics<2->[scale=.5]{SomeImage}
```

[turning Paul Gaborits comment into an CW answer; if you want to answer yourself, feel free to do so, I will delete this answer.]